# how can i order the columns in react js table

Tags: reactjs

I have a question that I would like to answer, please. I want to allow the user to arrange the columns of the table or specify what he wants to display in each column, such as Google Contacts. Do you have any suggestions for doing this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQV6f.png)

Comment: Can you add your current code? How are you displaying the data at the moment?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.